# redirect only after true oauth

Tags: facebook, sdk

is it possible the I will only load a app-page after a successfull oauth? Can I redirect to different pages if the oauth is successfull or not?

```
<body>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
FB.init({
        appId: '.....', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
FB.login({
      scope: 'email',
    });
</script>
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this may help you.

```
FB.login( function( response ) {
      if ( response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken ) {
        // redirect to SUCCESS
      } else {
        // redirect to FAILURE
      }
    }, { scope: 'email' } );
```

Comment: thx Julio, but can I use it in this way to redirect? It doesn't work but is there a possibility for? FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        if (response.perms) {
<? echo "Option 1"; ?>
self.location.href=='option1.php';
        } else {
   <? echo "Optionn 2"; ?>
self.location.href=='option2.php';
        }
      } else {
        // user is not logged in
      }
    }, {scope: 'email'});

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OAuth2? You really don't have to redirect at the point where you're waiting for the access_token to come back. There are several redirects in the OAuth2 process:

1. You direct the user to 
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
2. Once the user logs in (if necessary) and accepts your application, they are redirected back to your application (or at least to your redirect page). FB passes an authorization token in the querystring. **At this point, you don't need to redirect the user anymore.**
3. You can now send a request to the URL below, but you don't have to redirect the user to this url:
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URLclient_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=authorizationcode
4. FB returns the access_token in the body of the response.

You could then redirect your user based on that response. In other words, your user is sitting on the same page for steps 3 and 4, and at the end of step 4, you can redirect them somewhere else if you want to.

Comment: Thx for answer. It's a App which are used within different Fanpages, so I have not redirect_url. Will the redirect to the Appwork without this URl too?

Comment: This is coming from the following link: 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. 

You have to have the redirect page. When you register your app, you have to give it a site url to use the OpenGraph API, or at least to authenticate with OAUTH. This doesn't have to be the URL that your people go to to use your app, but it has to be where they're redirected after the OAuth dialog. From there, you can send them wherever they want. It's like your authentication "landing page." It can't be a redirector, but I think that you can have them land there and then send them somewhere else.